# Program that prints the digits of a number as characters (C language)

Tags: c

I have to do a program to take a number and print all the digits one by one as characters.

The code I have written is here:

```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   char digito(int, int);
   int numberofdigits(int);

   int main(void)
{
int num=0, test=0, kdigits=0, k=0;
char ch='\0';
printf("Enter a positive number:\n");
test=scanf("%d", &num);
if (teste!=1 || num<=0)
{
    printf("Error: not a valid number.\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

kdigits = numberofdigits(num);


for(k=0; k<kdigits; k++)
{
    ch= digito(num, k);
    printf("The digit %d of the number is %c\n", k, ch);
}

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}


int numberofdigits(int _n)
{
int count=0;
while (_n!=0)
{
    _n/=10;
    count++;
}

return count;
}


char digito(int _number, int _kdigit)
{
int flag=0, digit=0;
char ch='\0';
for (flag=0; flag<=_kdigit; flag++)
{
    digit=_number%10;
    _number/=10;
}

ch= digit + '0';
return ch;
}
```

Now the code is working pretty fine for relatively small numbers (up to 8 or 9 digits I would say).

But then something odd is happening: I tried to print the digits of the number 11111111111122 and obtained

The digit 0 of the number is 3;

The digit 1 of the number is 7;

The digit 2 of the number is 3;

The digit 3 of the number is 6;

The digit 4 of the number is 1;

The digit 5 of the number is 7;

The digit 6 of the number is 0;

The digit 7 of the number is 3;

I wonder why? Is it because it's a very large number? Because I tried even larger numbers and what happens is that the program enters the initial if clause that verifies the scanf reading. And that's ok. But the problem is that the program should also do the same with this number since it's bigger that the largest int. 
Can someone help me fix this please?

Thanks!

Comment: The number you are entering is most likely too large to be stored in an `int` (most compilers use 32bits for `int` which can store numbers up to 2,147,483,647) - you could try modifying your code to use `long long` (or `unsigned long long` if you disallow negative numbers) to allow larger inputs (though in a strict sense the standard does not guarantee that `long long` is larger than `int` most compilers implement it that way)

Comment: Did you use a debugger to see what's actually happening in the code?

Comment: @UnholySheep: but given what the standard does require, if `long long` is not bigger than `int`, then `int` is a 64-bit (or bigger) type, and the problem wouldn't have been spotted with the sample input.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler right, I confused the minimal size the standard requires (I thought it's 32bits, but that's for `long`, not `long long`)

Comment: See what `sizeof(int)` is in your system. If it's 4, that's a 32-bit signed number and the max is about 2E9. Exceeding that will lead to undefined behavior.

Comment: Note that decimal 11111111111122 is equivalent to 0xA1B01D4B1D2.  The low-order 32 bits of that value are 0x01D4B1D2, which maps to 30716370 decimal, which is more or less what was observed (30716373 — I'm not sure that I can account for the difference of 3).  The behaviour is not defined by the standard, but this is close to what is often observed as the undefined behaviour.  You should _not_ rely on this, though.

Comment: How can a correct scanf call lead to UB?! That sounds insane.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath :  all the numeric conversions in the `scanf()` family of functions are subject to the caveat that the value read must fit in the type or you get undefined behaviour. Check the POSIX Spec or a good man page.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: So you cannot use them with untrusted input. Wonderful... FYI: nothing mentioned at cppreference.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: Hmmm…POSIX [`scanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/scanf.html) says (quoting the C99 standard here): _Unless assignment suppression was indicated by a '`*`', the result of the conversion shall be placed in the object pointed to by the first argument following the format argument that has not already received a conversion result if the conversion specification is introduced by `%`, … If this object does not have an appropriate type, or if the result of the conversion cannot be represented in the space provided, the behavior is undefined._

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: And looking at CPPReference.com, [`fscanf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) there doesn't include the key information that the standard (C99, C11 — and POSIX by quoting the C99 standard) specifies about undefined behaviour.  To that extent, it is defective; that is quite important information.  (Looking at cplusplus.com, its [`fscanf()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/) description is even less thorough — I've not spent time investigating whether there are links to more/better information.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two answers to two questions:
Q1) Why do I get wrong digits for the example?
A1) As others have commented: Because the example number is too high for the data type used, it matches the number which you find in the lower 32 bits: 30716370.

Q2) Why is the initial check "<0" not triggering for the example but does trigger for other, higher examples?
A2) Because the 30716370 is smaller than the biggest positive number which can be represented by a 32 bit signed int, which is 2147483647 == 0x7FFFFFFF. That one however is smaller (even in the number of digits, but that is not the point) than 11111111111122.
30716370 <
2147483647 <
11111111111122
The even higher numbers will by chance have the bit31 set, which makes the lower 32bit look negative. You could probably find other numbers which are too high but do not seem negative.

Comment: Complement-1 or complement-2 representation of negative numbers is probably irrelevant for the problem. Both have bit31 set for negative numbers.